# What is the 'Resource Root' designation for in PHPStorm? For that matter, what does PHPStorm consider to be a resource?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Maybe I'm being thick, but I fail to understand what the 'Resource Root' button/designation is for when creating a project in PHPStorm. Having looked at [the PHPStorm documentation on the topic](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/content-root.html), the only explanation I've found is a variation on the following:

> "Resource Root: By assigning a folder to this category, you tell
>   PhpStorm that files in it and in its subfolders can be referenced
>   relative to this folder (instead of specifying full paths to them).
>   These folders are marked with the icon [purple directory]."

That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Questions about tools typically belong on Stack Overflow.  Please see the [help/on-topic] for information on questions that are appropriate for P.SE.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I can answer anecdotally that URL paths will be resolved against "resource roots" where applicable. For instance, in HTML `<a href="...">` or `<img src="...">` elements, relative URLs are looked up against resource roots. When you start typing within the `href` or `src` attributes, auto-completion will suggest items in those directories, and URLs which cannot be resolved will helpfully be marked as a warning.

Comment: So the site root is a/the resource root, then?

Comment: Basically yes, AFAIK.

Comment: So what it the different between source and resource?

Comment: @FreeLightman, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/content-root.html#root_types.